# Running script to get files from psftp

Tags: batch-file

I'm having some trouble and thought maybe someone could help me.  This is what I have so far:

```
call date2.cmd
md %DT_MM%-%DT_DD%-%DT_YYYY%
cd %DT_MM%-%DT_DD%-%DT_YYYY%
psftp servername.com -P port -l username -pw pass -b script to run while in server
```

So, I run date2 which gives me the correct date output it starts psftp but stops there.  I want to do an mget to grab all the files on the server and place them into the folder that I just created.   If anyone can help steer me in the right direction that would be appreciated.  I am sure I forgot some details, please let me know if there is any more information required.

Answer (score 0):

(Untested)

Make a script called `commands.txt` and change your `psftp` line to actually use it:

```
psftp servername.com -P port -l username -pw pass -b commands.txt
```

Then put some test commands in the script and see what happens:

```
pwd
quit
```

or maybe

```
mget *
quit
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use Putty  [plink.exe](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html)  .  I think it's much easier and it is scriptable and is able to handle or ignore prompting during the SSH session.  Would also work on linux.